# PHP timezone function not working

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I'm creating a forum, which also stores the time a post was sent, and I need to convert that into the user's timezone.
Now, the MySQL DataBase stores the time with `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` (in a column with the `DATETIME` type), and I created a little function from the code on http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/04/working-with-time-zones-in-php/ to convert the time to the user's timezone. This is the function:

```
function convertTZ($timestamp, $tz='UTC', $format='d-m-Y H:i:s') {
    // timestamp to convert
    $timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
    // the time formatting to use
    $format = $format;
    // the time zone provided
    $tz = $tz;

    // create the DateTimeZone object for later
    $dtzone = new DateTimeZone($tz);

    // first convert the timestamp into an RFC 2822 formatted date
    $time = date('r', $timestamp);

    // now create the DateTime object for this time
    $dtime = new DateTime($time);

    // convert this to the user's timezone using the DateTimeZone object
    $dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);

    // print the time using your preferred format
    $time = $dtime->format($format);

    return $time;
}
```

And I made a test page at http://assets.momo40k.ch/timezones.php.

Now, when I insert a post into the DataBase at, say, `11:50` in my timezone (which is `Europe/Rome`), it inserts `09:50` in UTC, wich is correct, according to some online timezone converters.
But when I try to convert it back to `Europe/Rome` with the `convertTZ()` function, it returns `09:50`, as if `Europe/Rome` is UTC. If I try converting it to a GMT+2:00 timezone, it returns `10:50`. Can anyone fugure out why this is?
P.S: I'm not using the `CONVERT_TZ()` `SQL` function because my server does not support named timezones, so this function is my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your stored timestamps are UTC:

```
$date = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date->format(DATE_W3C); // does it gives the expected result ?
```

BTW your function can be simplified to this:

```
function convertTZ($timestamp, $tz='UTC', $format='d-m-Y H:i:s') {
    $dtime = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone("UTC"))
    $dtime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    return $dtime->format($format);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. This still seems to be returning `25-08-2011 09:50:51` instead of `2011-08-25 11:50:51`, as it should be if one selects Europe/Rome in the demo's dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL always stores TIMESTAMP fields in UTC internally (that's the definition of a unix timestamp, in fact). So when you SELECT or UPDATE/INSERT/REPLACE, the time you get or set is always in the MySQL server's local time zone.

So a common mistake is to store UTC_TIMESTAMP(), which MySQL interprets as a local time and so the current time gets double-converted to UTC when it stores it internally in the field as a unix TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Does the double-conversio issue still apply if one uses `CONVERT_TZ()` to `SELECT`? Also, my column type is `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Any field that you get or set will be in the local time zone for those operations. So if you SELECT with CONVERT_TZ, CONVERT_TZ will take as input a time field in the server's local time zone.

Comment: DATETIME fields are stored as-is, I believe, so you just need to make sure that if you do any conversions on UPDATE, you also do the reverse on SELECT. You should also be aware that some timezone mapping functions are not 1-to-1, see the note at the end of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll be aware of it. Still, I can't understand why it seems to be taking Europe/Rome as if it were UTC (because any timezone then has the offset from Europe/Rome). It seems it's skipping two timezones ahead

Comment: Europe/Rome should not equal UTC, you are correct. Just double-check your code and that you typed the time-zone name correctly.

Comment: `So a common mistake is to store UTC_TIMESTAMP(), which MySQL interprets as a local time` -- I'm pretty sure this is wrong. `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` returns the UTC date and time, no `local time` is involved.

Comment: Nate: When you UPDATE/INSERT/REPLACE a TIMESTAMP field, the query will interpret the string returned by UTC_TIMESTAMP() as a local time.